# Set Default Shell in Cygwin

Tags: shell, cygwin, fish

I've been using Cygwin for quite a while now. I now want to switch to fish from bash. Everyone is saying that you should use `chsh -s /usr/bin/fish`, but for some reason, `chsh` does not work for me. Trying to modify my `Cygwin.bat` file doesn't work either, and neither does changing my `/etc/passwd` file.

I really don't understand what's going on. Could someone please help me?

Comment: Did you add /usr/bin/fish to /etc/shells?

Comment: I did, and it didn't work.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I randomly meet the same problem, and now I providing my solution for you.

0- Open `cygwin` by `mintty.exe`

1- Build passwd file manually (`mkpasswd`)

```
$mkpasswd > /etc/passwd
```

2- Change default shell in passwd file

```
$vim /etc/passwd
user:*:1976XX:1971XX:U-user\user,S-1-5-21-XXXX:/home/user:/bin/fish
```

3- Restart `mintty.exe`

Comment: Very helpful! Thanks

Comment: Don't be off-put by the fact that `/etc/passwd` doesn't exist prior to this, as it would in Linux.

Comment: This does not with when you use Cygwin with Windows Terminal, to use zsh with Windows Terminal edit the Cygwin.bat and change `cd /d "%~dp0bin" && .\bash --login -i` to `cd /d "%~dp0bin" && .\zsh --login -i`

Answer (score 44):

## Try editing /etc/nsswitch.conf instead of /etc/passwd

Instead of creating a passwd file, which Cygwin [recommends against](https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/mkpasswd.html)<sup>1</sup>, you could [edit /etc/nsswitch.conf](https://www.cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/ntsec.html#ntsec-mapping-nsswitch).  Add or edit the following line:

```
db_shell: /usr/bin/fish
```

The down/up side of this method is that, if you have multiple users, this change affects all of them.  The up/up side is that it's dead simple.  The only catch is that you have to restart Cygwin.

If you *do* use `mkpasswd` after this change, it will use your new default shell for all users that are allowed to log on.

---

## References

<sup>1</sup> The `mkpasswd` documentation says this:

> Don't use this command to generate a local /etc/passwd file, unless you really need one. See the Cygwin User's Guide for more information.

I can't really find any solid reasoning in the [user's guide](https://www.cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/cygwin-ug-net.html), other than a mention that you'll have to regenerate the `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/group` files if your users and groups change, which I suppose is a decent enough reason.  I can say that the process is somewhat error prone for newbies.

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work for me even after restarting `mintty`. Also, the `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/group` are both nowhere to be found in my system. I used the default Cygwin installation with no modifications at all. If anyone could help, that would be appreciated.

Comment: I was finally able to set `zsh` as the default shell in Cygwin after reading David Paktor's answer to the following question: https://superuser.com/questions/351435/zsh-with-cygwin

Answer (score 7):

There's an answer on [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/a/1134672/197972) that is even simpler.  Set the SHELL environment variable in Windows.  Set it to your preferred shell (e.g. `/bin/tcsh`) and newly-launched shells should use it.

To set environment variables:

1. Go to the "System" control panel (right-click on the Start menu and select "System")
2. Click on "Advanced system settings" in the left-side column
3. From the "System Properties" window that pops up, click the "Environment Variables..." button
4. In either the "User variables" or "System variables" box (depending on whether you want the change to affect just yourself or all users), click the "New..." button.
5. Type "SHELL" in the "Variable name" box and the path (relative to the Cygwin file system) to your preferred shell in the "Variable value" box.
6. Click OK on the three open windows to save your changes.

Comment: I see this working when running the mintty terminal, but not when I connect through ssh.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure how 'proper' of a solution this is, but I just added `/usr/bin/zsh; exit` to the bottom of my `.bashrc` file. You can substitute `/usr/bin/zsh` for the path to your shell of choice. It seems to work just fine so far.

Comment: I've already voted for your answer  2 years ago. I came here again looking for the same and can't vote anymore. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If you're running Cygwin through **ConEmu** I found the easiest way is to replace commands line to run fish instead of default shell (*Settings->Startup->Tasks*):
`""c:\cygwin64\bin\fish.exe" --login -i"` (please change path to your cygwin folder accordingly)

Answer (score 3):

I wanted to comment on the accepted answer, but not enough rep.

Regarding this method

`$ mkpasswd > /etc/passwd`

While this works to generate an /etc/passwd file, the odds are you're installing cygwin for yourself, and if your computer belongs to a domain, mkpasswd may run out and attempt to consume the entire domain user list.  I had a 500MB+ /etc/passwd file from exactly this condition, and cygwin wouldn't even start until I deleted the file.

I strongly recommend, if using the mkpasswd route to use the `-c` switch, so it puts an entry in only for yourself.

`$ mkpasswd -c > /etc/passwd`

On a machine with a shared cygwin service (assuming you have write permissions)

`$ mkpasswd -c >> /etc/passwd`

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to change my default shell in cygwin to zsh and I found parts of the answers 
 here helpful, but none of them gave a full solution.  The best instructions I found were in the "installing zsh" instruction in the oh my zsh github repo by Robby Russel that you can find [here](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/wiki/Installing-ZSH)

At the top of the page it has general instructions for installing zsh and then specific instructions for many different platforms.  You can scroll down to the Cygwin section and follow the steps:

"The easiest way to change the default shell is to set your SHELL user environment variable. Search for "Edit Environment variables for your account" to bring up the environment variables window, create a new variable named "SHELL" and give it the value "/usr/bin/zsh/"."

(On Windows 7:
Press Windows key.
Start typing "environment".
When it appears, select "Edit environment variables for your account" and add the new variable as stated above.)

After I did this I closed and reopened my Cygwin shell window and tested that it worked with echo $SHELL. Expected result: /bin/zsh or similar.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

This question was written in 2014, back when Cygwin still created an `etc/passwd` file by default.

In more recent versions of Cygwin, no `etc/passwd` file is created by default, and Cygwin has recommended against using it (presumably because Cygwin now reads directly from Windows account databases), instead recommending users to edit `/etc/nsswitch.conf`, as P Daddy said in his answer.

However, editing `/etc/nsswitch.conf` didn't help me, so I decided to create an `etc/passwd` file after all, and that indeed solved my problem, letting me set `zsh` as my default shell in Cygwin.

To do what I did, simply enter the command

`mkpasswd -c | sed -e 'sX/bashX/zshX' | tee -a /etc/passwd`

More details can be found in the following answer, which is where I got the command:

https://superuser.com/a/891728/1036875

Answer (score 0):

Go to `c:\cygwin` or `c:\cygwin64` (whatever is your cygwin home directory) and edit `cygwin.bat`. Instead of

```
bash --login -i
```

write, for example,

```
rem bash --login -i
tcsh -l
```

Answer (score 0):

One simple way to do this is call tcsh at the end of .bashrc file

```
#     x2=$(dirs +${cnt} 2>/dev/null)
#     [[ $? -ne 0 ]] && return 0
#     [[ ${x2:0:1} == '~' ]] && x2="${HOME}${x2:1}"
#     if [[ "${x2}" == "${the_new_dir}" ]]; then
#       popd -n +$cnt 2>/dev/null 1>/dev/null
#       cnt=cnt-1
#     fi
#   done
#
#   return 0
# }
#
# alias cd=cd_func
tcsh
alias g=gvim
source ~/.cshrc
source ~/.aliases
```